# angular directive - dynamic group $watch similar models

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wondering how I can get similar models to watch each other for changes.  Each group is dynamic with an unspecified number of other members in it's group.  In the example below, we would want similar inputs to auto fill IF the other variants are already empty.  For example filling in the title will copy and populate to any other empty "titlevariants" in that group.  Any changes to promotext will copy and populate to any other empty "subtitlevariants".  What's the angular way of doing that?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" groupcheck="titlevariants" />
<input type="text" ng-model="metatitle" groupcheck="titlevariants" />
<input type="text" ng-model="headertitle" groupcheck="titlevariants" />
<input type="text" ng-model="path" groupcheck="titlevariants" groupcheckfunction="urlencode" />

<input type="text" ng-model="promotext" groupcheck="subtitlevariants" />
<input type="text" ng-model="subtext" groupcheck="subtitlevariants" />
```

Is there any way to create a 'groupcheck' directive that lumps models with similars values into a common watch?  Here's a pseudoish example of a directive that comes close to doing it ...

```
angular.module('Module').directive('groupCheck', function () {
   function link(scope, element, attrs) {
          //Psuedo code....
          scope.$watch(/*something like */ attr.groupCheck) {
          //find all other elements
          //for silliness jquery would do this:
          $('[groupcheck="' + element.attr('groupcheck') '"]').each(function() {
             if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val(element.value);
             }
             if (typeof $(this).attr('groupcheckfunction') !== 'undefined') {
                 //.... more code here
             }
          });
       }
   }
   //.....
});
```

I don't want to use jquery since it goes without saying it that creates other problems, but I'm just using that pseudo snippet to explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should forget the jQuery way...

Even in directives (where you are *allowed* to manipulate the dom, you do have models and data bindings and you should (*almost*) never have to actually access the dom itself (like you do with jQuery) for taking care of data bindings (via jQuery's `value` or `attr` methods).

The recommended approach is to make use of the `ngForm` directive (among it's validation scope values such as [`$pristine`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$pristine)) and to pass the actual model that you want to watch onto the new created directive:

```
angular.module('Module', []).directive('groupCheck', function () {

    var link = function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        // watch for any changes in the model that we check on
        scope.$watch('groupCheck', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // if the user hasn't touched the input
            if(ctrl[scope.name] && ctrl[scope.name].$pristine) {
                // if we do provide a function
                if(scope.groupCheckFunction) {
                    scope.model = scope.groupCheckFunction(newVal); 
                } else {
                    scope.model = newVal;
                }
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        // let's restrict this directive to an attribute declaration
        restrict: 'A',
        // we need to use the form controller
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            groupCheck: '=',
            groupCheckFunction: '=',
            model: '=ngModel',
            name: '@'
        },
        link: link
    };
});
```

So basically, this directive tells an input to be in sync with another one (another model in fact) if it's pristine (the user never touched it).

Other solutions may also work, but this approach is cleaner because it is *jQuery-less* and it forces you to think more *angularish*.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/4UTW8/) that shows this code in action.

Comment: `if(ctrl[scope.name] && ctrl[scope.name].$pristine)` where do you get that from? I mean... really.. where? :o. That looks quite advanced compared to my stuff.

Comment: By telling the directive to require something (`require: '^form'`), it looks up for that specific controller and injects it in the directive link (and controller) function. You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: what gets me is the scope.name selection, it looks like the ctrl object is a hash/collection and you are selecting a particular controller with the name of the input... I have read hints that you could do that in the docs but I never saw explicit code that does it.

Comment: The form controller constructs a model for each of it's named children (input/select/textarea...) in order to do it's validation magic. The `$pristine` property is alsow part of the validation logic of the form controller. The tricky part in my example was to access the exact input from the form controller in my directive, which I accomplished by adding the `name` as aread-only property in the directive's scope.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way would be to add a `ng-change` property to your inputs and assign all of them to the same method. I haven't used `ng-change` much but that should work.

I have edited your directive also:

```
app.directive('groupCheck', function ($rootScope) {
   scope: { group: '&groupcheck' },
   function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      //Pseudo code....
      scope.$watch(function(){ return element.val(); }, function(new, old) {
        // tell all other elements
        if(new!==old){ $rootScope.$broadcast('onTellAllYourFriends', scope.group, new); }
      });   

      scope.$on('onTellAllYourFriends', function(event, group, value){
        if(group=== scope.group){ // party time! }
      });       
   }


});
```

This is still a bit pseudo code but that should work.

Edit: The directive should be called groupcheck if it is defined as groupcheck in the html. :)

Comment: ng-change only affects one element, without knowing the others similarly named variants ahead of time, how would it find the other models in that group?  (I changed the title to mention "dynamic group" to hopefully clarify)

Comment: @Parmenides what I am saying is that you can have 10000 `ng-change` on  10000 different inputs, but if they all point to the same method, you are in business, I think you can pass the input value as a parameter. Alternatively, you could use that directive in your example and just replace `/* something like */` by `function(){ return element.val(); }` or so.